# I was trying to compile an android app and getting this error

Tags: android

i was trying to compile an android app and getting this error can anyone help

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':ListViewAnimations-core-slh:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [android - AS:StickyListHeaders:unspecified] F:\material-design-ui_v11\UPDATE\android\android - AS\ListViewAnimations-core-slh\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android - AS\StickyListHeaders\unspecified\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders" to force usage
```

Comment: Your error clearly says to change min sdk version

Comment: min sdk version must match in your manifest and gradle both files, it colud be define 7 at one place and 1 at another by mistake, so correct it

Comment: i am just new to this and not getting where is the error and just trying to edit one template if you can tell me where i have to change this that would be great

Comment: in AndroidManifest.xml and gradle.build file you have to change this value